# Ejecutar SQLCMD desde un JOB

Tags: sql, sql-server, base-de-datos

Buenas tardes compañeros, necesito su ayuda para saber que está pasando con mi `JOB` ya que no realiza la acción que quiero. Les comento que hice un `Stored Procedure` para mandar a llamar un `JOB` el cual ejecuta una línea de comando `SQLCMD` para crear un archivo `.txt` con la información de una consulta, sin embargo no me está creando el archivo `.txt`, a continuación les dejo la información:

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROC testjob
AS
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job N'GetDataFromPagos'
```

**SQLCMD**

```
sqlcmd -S myserver -U "sa" -P "Password" -d clientes -Q "SELECT TOP 5 * FROM CLIENTES..PAGOS" -o C:\Employees.txt
```

**Imagen de JOB**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No se si me hace falta realizar alguna otra acción, al momento de ejecutar mi `stored procedure` me muestra el siguiente mensaje:

```
 Job 'GetDataFromPagos' started successfully.
```

Al parecer dice que inicia satisfactoriamente, sin embargo no se que falte para que me cree el archivo.

**Nota Adicional**: Les comento que ejecuté el `SQLCMD` desde la línea de comandos (`cmd`) y funcionó correctamente.

Se les agradece su ayuda.
Saludos.

Comment: Que MySQL estas usando? amigo

Comment: ¿Y que te dice el job history?

Comment: @Juan Carlos estoy utilizando SqlServer 2012

Comment: @Patricio te comento que en el View History me muestra "The Job succeeded", también me muestra la información de la fecha y el usuario correspondiente que ejecutó el Job (En este caso "sa").

Comment: Una disculpa compañeros, al parecer todo estaba correcto, tuve una confusión con respecto a la ubicación del archivo, de igual modo les agradezco su atención.

Answer (score 1):

Por lo que se ve en la imagen del JOB, seguramente la cuenta en el "Run As" no tiene privilegios para escribir el archivo en donde especificas.

Lo que yo he hecho es lo siguiente:

1. Crear una credencial, asociándola con una identidad existente en SQL Server, un LOGIN, que tenga permisos de escritura en el disco duro. Aquí no te funcionará uno de tipo SQL, debe ser de tipo Windows. La contraseña es de dicho LOGIN, no uno asociado a la credencial.
2. Crear un proxy, asignándole la credencial creada en el paso anterior. En dicho proxy, activar el subsistema "Operating System (CmdExec)".
3. Editar el paso en el JOB y en la casilla "Run As" seleccionar el proxy creado anteriormente.

Con lo anterior, el job desde el procedimiento almacenado ya te debe crear el archivo.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, al parecer tenía todo correcto, solo tuve cierta confusión en cuanto a la ubicación del archivo, de igual modo agradezco tu información.